# Typescript Error, not sure what is causing the error with the complier

Tags: typescript

Not sure what's causing the error here with the typescript error. I've tried uninstall and reinstalling the node packages for the react front end and im not sure what's causing the compile problem here

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import { FieldRenderProps } from 'react-final-form';
import { FormFieldProps, Form, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {DateTimePicker} from 'react-widgets';
interface IProps
  extends FieldRenderProps<Date, HTMLInputElement>,
    FormFieldProps {}
const DateInput: React.FC<IProps> = ({
    input,
    width,
    placeholder,
    date = false,
    time = false,
    meta: { touched, error },
    ...rest
  }) => {
    return (
        <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
        <DateTimePicker 
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={input.value || null}
            onChange={input.onChange}
            onBlur={input.onBlur}
            onKeyDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
            date={date}
            time={time}
            {...rest}
        />
        {touched && error && (
          <Label basic color='red'>
            {error}
          </Label>
        )}
      </Form.Field>
    )
}
export default DateInput
```

Comment: Try removing `{...rest}` from your DateTimePicker props. If what you are passing into `DateTimePicker` doesn't match the definition of `DateTimePickerProps` then you will get that error. For example: seems like you are passing in an `id` prop that is not supported.

Comment: I removed ```{...rest}``` from the props and it's still getting the error. I added id=null; and I am still getting an error for typescript. 

```
Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.  TS2322
```